# How do I get the cake in Portal?

Tags: portal

In Portal, I am continually told that I will

> be receiving cake for all my hard work

but in the final room I keep dying.

How do I avoid dying so that I can

> get the cake?

Comment: @Ala: I agree with you: now that you edited the title, it works really better! And the body gives a nice vision of what you are actually seeking for.

Comment: **The cake is a lie.** Downvote me if you will, but it had to be said)

Comment: When I died in the fire, I thought that was the end of the game. How edgy and hip of valve to kill you. It was a year before I found out there was more to the game - much more!

Comment: This question was a triumph.  I'm making a note here: Huge Success.  It's hard to overstate my satisfaction.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to think with Portals!

Look up in the direction you are heading to the fire; you can spawn a portal on the wall up there, one to your right, and teleport out of danger.

After that, keep trying to reach the party to get your promised cake!

Comment: Though I would not wait for the party associates to take me there...

Comment: @Gno, I guess you didn't see what the latest update to the game does ;)

Comment: Juan > What would that be?  Is this only relevant to certain versions of the game, for example the PC version?

Comment: @Gnome, beware, it has spoilers (video of the new ending): http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2010/03/03/valve-wont-let-us-sleep-portal-updates/#more-26402

Comment: @Juan > ...intense.

Comment: As a relative noob to gaming in those days, it took be about 30 minutes after escaping certain death to realize that I was, in fact, **not** breaking the game, but rather playing it as it was intended. In my defense, Portal was described as "a demo" by the friend who suggested I play it.

Answer (score 15):

You should try to escape from the room with the fire without dying. The cake is... later.

Answer (score 7):

If you shoot a portal above the flames, and a portal on a wall you can jump into, you will get onto the shelf above them. In my opinion, it is about this point that the fun really gets started... (Hint - this is not then end of the game, by a long way!)

Comment: The game really starts to get interesting at this point:-)